# How to launch widget configuration after is been put on screen

Tags: android, button, widget, android-intent

My widget launches a configuration screen when chosen to be put on screen. That works fine.
I wanted to be able to touch a part of the widget to return to that configuration screen.
I have created 2 pending intents in my widget's service but only one works. The code is below:

```
remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.my_image,myWidget.makeControlPendingIntent(getApplicationContext(),BUTTON1,appWidgetId));
remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.TextViewBat,myWidget.makeControlPendingIntent(getApplicationContext(),BUTTON2,appWidgetId));
```

and before those 2 at the beggining of the service the code to choose what to do:

```
if(command.equals(BUTTON1)){
        Intent firstIntent = new Intent(this, anotherActivity.class);
        firstIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(firstIntent); //THIS WORKS
    }
else if(command.equals(BUTTON2)){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "the prefs button is clicked",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //THIS WORKS
        /*Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(myIntent);*/  //THIS WORKS

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,myConfiguration.class);
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(myIntent); //* * * THIS CRASHES * * * *

    }
```

For the life of me i cannot understand how i can launch again the configuration activity.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is call `getActivity()` on `PendingIntent`, for an `Intent` that is your configuration activity, and tie that to something in the app widget via `setOnClickPendingIntent()`. Here is [a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget/Microblog/) demonstrating this.